# Quick select different pivot selection algorithms results

Tags: c, algorithm, probability, quicksort

I wrote the following quick-select randomize algorithm that moves the smallest k elements of an array to the beginning of it in linear time (technically worst case O(n^2) but the probability drops exponentially):

```
// This function moves the smallest k elements of the array to
// the beginning of it in time O(n).
void moveKSmallestValuesToTheLeft( double       arr[] ,
                                   unsigned int n     ,
                                   unsigned int k     )
{
    int l = 0, r = n - 1; //Begginning and end indices of the array
    while (0 < k && k < n && n > 10)
    {
        unsigned int partition_index, left_size, pivot;

        //Partition the data around a random pivot
        pivot           = generatePivot(arr, l, n, k); //explained later
        partition_index = partition(arr, l, r, pivot); //standard quick sort partition
        left_size       = partition_index - l + 1;

        if (k < left_size)
        {
            //Continue with left subarray
            r = partition_index - 1;
            n = partition_index - l;
        }
        else
        {
            //Continue with right subarray
            l += left_size;
            n -= left_size;
            k -= left_size;
        }
    }
    if (n <= 10)
        insertionSort(arr + l, n);
}
```

And I tested 3 different methods for generating pivot all of them are based on selecting 5 random candidates and returning one of them, for each method I ran the code 100,000. These were the methods:

1. Choose random 5 elements and return their median
2. Choose random 5 elements, calculate k/n and check which element of the 5 is closest to it. I.e, if `k/n <= 1/5` return the min if `k/n <= 2/5` return the second smallest value, if `k/n <= 3/5` return the median and so on.
3. Exactly the same as method 2 but we give more weight to the pivots closer to the median based on the binomial coefficients of them, i.e. I calculated the binomial coefficients for `n=5-1` and got `[1 4 6 4 1]` then I normalized them and calculated their cum-sum and got `[0.0625 0.3125, 0.6875 0.9375 1]` and then I did: If `k/n <= 0.0625` return the min, if `k/n <= 0.3125` return the second smallest value, if `k/n <= 0.6875` return the median and so on...

My intuition told me that method 2 would perform the best because it always chooses the pivot that would most likely be closest to the k'th smallest element and therefore would probably decrease k or n the most at each iteration, but instead every time I ran the code I got the following results (ranked fastest method to slowest method based an average and worst case times):

**Average running time:**

```
First place (fastest): Method 3
Second place: Method 2
Last place: Method 1
```

**Worst case running time:**

```
First place (fastest): Method 1
Second place: Method 3
Last place: Method 2
```

My question is is there any mathematical way to explain these results or at least give some intuition to them? Because my intuition was completely wrong method 2 didn't outperform neither of the other 2 methods.

**EDIT**

So apparently the problem was that I only tested `k=n/2` which is an edge case so I got this weird results.

Comment: How were the data chosen for your 100000 test runs?  Were they the same data every time, for every algorithm?  Or was it maybe 100000 different data sets, each one tested against each algorithm? Or something else?

Comment: @JohnBollinger each time the data was different, I created 10000 random integers half of them were negative and half of them were positive and shuffled the array, then I called the function with k=n/2, and checked both running time and that the first n/2 are negative and the rest are positive (which they were), also just to be more precise in the worst case instead of testing time I tested the sum of the number of elements the partition was passed on (i.e. the sum of n's at each partition call).

Comment: Ok.  It would be a better experiment to test each algorithm on the same series of data sets, but I suspect that would produce the same trend.

Comment: You should include the information about the size of the data sets in the question, @TomerWolberg.  What were the actual times you recorded (at least the mean and worst case times)?  Did you try other data set sizes than 10,000 entries?  What values of `k` were you testing with?  How did you establish the time taken — what techniques were you using to measure the time?  Benchmarking is an endlessly frustrating process — it is very hard to make good tests.

Comment: Note that *k* = *n* / 2 is one of the boundary cases for the problem in question.  There's nothing wrong with testing that case, but by itself, it doesn't give you a very complete picture.  It may also be relevant to the particular algorithms being considered that when the parameters have that relationship, the problem is equivalent to that of finding the median of the data set.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I measured the time by number of elements the algorithm checks, i.e. I summed 'n' each time before the partition call. I tried anywhere between 100 and 100,000 entries. For the 10,000 entries I got averages of `2.22n, 2.34n, 2.5n` and worse cases of  `4.89n, 5.03n, 7.28n`. Before reading the comments I only tried `k=n/2` but now after reading the comments I tried `k=n/4, 3/4n` and I got that as I expected method 2 would be faster and I also got an average of `50n` which shows how much of an edge case `k=n/2` really is. So the problem was in the test for testing only `k=n/2`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Your'e right, that was the problem